# how to create new table based on another existing table and keep the data format using sqlite

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am trying to create table for the decomposed set which decomposed by BCNF, but I really do not know how to keep the format.
what I am doing is to get a list contain the part to describe the data format(I am using python), for example:

```
['A INT,B INT,C INT,H REAL,K REAL', 'A INT,D INT', 'B INT,E INT,H REAL', 'A INT,F TEXT', 'E INT,F TEXT', 'B INT,G TEXT,H REAL']
```

And I try do something like this:

```
c.execute("CREATE TABLE %s (%r PRIMARY KEY '%r' ) ;" %(dataList[n],schemas[n],key))
```

I want to get something like this:

[image]

However, the result is like this:

[image]

So, how can I do that?
(I know using string constructors is not secure but I don't know other way to do it.)

Comment: Instead of executing directly an expression, build the sql string and display it. You should immediately understand where the problem lies.

Comment: Constructing an SQL statement from partial strings is unsafe only if some attacker can control some of those strings.